# CMake Shared Library: how to specify different output directories for DLL and LIB files?

Tags: cmake

### Background

Given a shared library I am creating with CMake:

```
add_library(SharedLib SHARED sharedlib.cpp shared_exports.h)
target_include_directories(SharedLib PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/libshared)
include(GenerateExportHeader)
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER(SharedLib
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME SHARED_EXPORTS
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/libshared/shared_exports.h)
```

It creates 5 files:

SharedLib.dll
SharedLib.exp
SharedLib.ilk
SharedLib.lib
SharedLib.pdb

Which is great. All output files go to a directory that I specify in a global CMakeLists.txt.

### Question

But I would like to separately specify that the DLL and it's corresponding PDB file go into my master build directory somewhere else. (Leaving the .lib file where it is)

I have tried so many combinations of:

```
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

using different variables that it's made my head spin.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output directories for different build artifacts are regulated by different CMake **variables** (and corresponded properties):

- `.dll` - [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)
- `.lib` - [CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)
- `.pdb` - [CMAKE_COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)

Example:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/pdb)

add_library(SharedLib SHARED sharedlib.cpp shared_exports.h)
```

Comment: Do these set commands have to come before or after the call to `add_library` ? Looks like it MUST be set before in order to work.

Comment: Note that this almost works for me. I had modified CMAKE_BINARY_DIR in the top level CMakeLists.txt file. Thus I found that CMAKE_BINARY_DIR changes depending on which CMakeLists.txt file is getting invoked. So I had to use this:

Comment: No, do never set `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` variable: CMake assumes it points to the top build directory, and some features may suddenly break if it is not true.

Comment: Ok, I thanks for the advice, I will look into changing that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works:

```
# Top level CMakeLists.txt file:

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
```

And in my **src/libShared/CMakeLists.txt** file I had to put the `set` command BEFORE the call to `add_library`

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH})
add_library(SharedLib SHARED sharedlib.cpp shared_exports.h)
```

otherwise, I found the hard way, I could to set the property AFTER the call to `add_library` like this:

```
set_target_properties(SharedLib PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}
)
```